# asp.net checkbox custom validation

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to make a website using the ASP.NET Dynamic Data entities and I need a checkbox in my website that must be checked in order to insert a new record. However I am having trouble validating the checkbox. I have tried server side custom validators that people have postes on this website but for aome reason they aren't working..any clue on if the implementation will be different if its a dynamic data entity application?

These are the different things I have tried so far:

Attempt 1:

Made a new class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

And then called it from the metadata file in the following way:

[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage="Error")]

public bool Checkbox12 { get; set; }

That doesn't work.

Then I tried something else:

Attempt 2:

on the aspx page:

```
<asp:DynamicControl ID="MyCheckbox" runat="server" DataField="Checkbox12" Mode="Insert" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvIsActive"   OnServerValidate="cvIsActive_ServerValidate">You must select the checkbox</asp:CustomValidator>
```

and on the aspx.cs page:

```
 protected void cvIsActive_ServerValidate(object source,ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {           
       if(args.Value.Length==1)
            args.IsValid = true;
        else
            args.IsValid = false;   

    }
```

---

The 2nd attempt gives me the error message whether it is clicked or not.
I tried replacing the the args.value.length with :

args.IsValid = MyCheckBox.Checked

However this gives an error that the name MyCheckBox does not exist in the current context

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add your code and which part of your code is not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {//Do your Code here..
    }
```